# How to prevent dangling reference to an iterator instance

Tags: c++

```
template<typename T>
class IteratorLike
{
public:
    ...
    boost::shared_ptr<T> operator->() { // return pointer
        return shpContainedObj;
    }   

    T& operator*() { // return reference
        return *shpContainedObj;
    }

private:
    ...
    boost::shared_ptr<T> shpContainedObj;
};
```

This class is not a real iterator but a wrapper class that encapusulates the underlying type T. Some type of T is NOT copyable. I realize I may run into problems if the user call operator*() and then hold the reference to T&. In the case, the shared_ptr shpContainedObj is destroyed due to out of scope then the reference to T& will be a dangling reference.

Any good suggestion?
One bad solution is to disable the operator*() and only allow the operator->()

Comment: I think you may be over thinking this. no one cares that you can dereference the boost::shared_ptr which could lead to a dangling reference. At some point you have to trust your users to not be total idiots. You can make it 100% their fault not not exposing a dereference operator and allow them to get copies to of the underlying shared pointer with a "get shared ptr" method, but they'd STILL be able to dereference that.

Comment: ok. I got the message!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your user does this:

```
std::vector<int> x(10);
int & ref = x.front();
x.clear();

use(ref);
```

Then you have a bad user.

The normal expectation (that I would have) is that my libraries won't protect me from doing this.

Comment: What if I'm the user and I put an accidental &?

Comment: @EfForEffort: I'd recommend using tools like [Address Sanitizer](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/AddressSanitizer.html) to help detect use-after-free issues like this.